# Exception "Received fatal alert: handshake_failure" while sending a request through java code

Tags: java

**Note:** Same url is working successfully in browser, but it’s not working through java program same url.
**Java code:**

```
String urlString= "https://<host>:<port>/TestProject";
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)     System.out.println(inputLine);
in.close();
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1720)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1165)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1149)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
```

Please give the solutions as early as possible for this. Please give the possibilities to get this scenario if knows, it will very useful for me.

**Finally i got solution:**

Please look into http://myjavacafe.blogspot.in/2015/01/exception-received-fatal-alert.html

Answer (score 0):

**First:** the server probably logged more detailed information about the problem, which could allow determining and fixing the actual problem. But since you want an early and "possible" answer rather than an accurate one, causes I've seen are:

**Version too old:** The server requires a newer protocol than your Java client offers. You appear to be running Java6, which only implements up to TLSv1.0. If the server demands higher, it will fail the handshake, although requiring above 1.0 is somewhat controversial for now (it likely will become accepted and common over the next several years). **Solution:** use Java8 (in its default configuration), or at least Java7 and override its default configuration which only offers up to TLSv1.0 for client.

**Version too new:** TLS specs (all) call for servers to negotiate a newer-version or otherwise more-capable client down to the server capabilities, but some servers apparently have bugs and instead fail the handshake. (Browsers/clients often handle this by falling back to older protocols, which caused the recent "POODLE" attack. See for example https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71427/is-java-client-vulnerable-by-poodle and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70719/ssl3-poodle-vulnerability .) However, Java6 client is unlikely to trigger such a problem, and if a recent browser and especially several recent browsers can connect **this is very unlikely**. But if this is the problem **Solution:** use older Java (poor), or configure to use old protocol version(s) and possibly few(er) ciphers.

**Extensions:** Similarly it is possible a buggy server fails to skip unimplemented extensions as the specs say it should. Again if modern browsers can connect **this is very unlikely**. But if it does you can't control the extensions Java uses so **Solution:** none. (At least none in Java. You could use an external adapter such as stunnel, or an application-level proxy or relay.)

**No shared cipher:** The server does not support any of the ciphersuites your client offers. **This is unlikely** unless your JRE/JVM is configured badly. Java implements nearly all the defined ciphersuites, and by default enables all the ones that are not badly insecure, except that Java6 only enables Elliptic Curve Cryptography suites if an ECC crypto provider is installed which it is not by default. A server admin might reasonably want and prefer EC, but to require it today would be imprudent. **If ECC** is the problem **Solution:** use Java7 or 8 or add an EC provider to Java6. **If your JRE/JVM is configured badly** to use insecure ciphersuites  that the server *should* not agree to **Solution:** don't do that.

**SNI:** The server may fail the handshake if it requires Server Name Indication, an extension commonly required nowadays for virtual hosting, but your client does not provide it with the right value. However, Java6 URLConnection(https) derives SNI automatically from the URL, the same way browsers do, so if the same URL works in a recent browser that is not the problem.

**Client auth**: The server may require client authentication using a certificate, often abbreviated as requiring (a) client cert, and fail if your client doesn't provide one, or perhaps not the correct one. Your browser(s) may be configured to supply the correct cert&key automatically, although if you use multiple browsers that don't share a keystore (as for example IE and Chrome on Windows do) that may be less likely. **Solution:** configure your JVM/JRE (or for limited scope a customized SSLSocketFactory) to use a keystore that contains the correct privateKeyEntry (key and cert or chain) or if a keystore is already configured put the correct privateKeyEntry in that keystore.